# What is C++ doing when I use the comma operator in the initializer expressions?

Tags: c++, initializer-list, comma-operator

My program was crashing, no debugger readily available, so I spiked it with printfs, narrowed it down to the (lengthy) initializer list, and tried to get it to show which initializer expression causes the crash, by stuffing `printf(...),`  before each expression, so it looked something like this:

```
#include <cstdio>

class X
{
public:
    int a_;
    int b_;
    X(int a, int b);
};

X::X(int a, int b) :
    a_(printf("Initializing a\n"), a),
    b_(printf("Initializing b\n"), b)
{}


int main() {
    X x(1,2);
    return 0;
}
```

My reasoning was the comma operator should swallow the return value of printf, execute the following expression, and initialize the property as normal. Instead, I got an error:

```
hw.cpp: In constructor 'X::X(int, int)':
hw.cpp:12:5: error: expression list treated as compound expression in mem-initializer [-fpermissive]
   12 |     a_(printf("Initializing a\n"), a),
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
hw.cpp:13:5: error: expression list treated as compound expression in mem-initializer [-fpermissive]
   13 |     b_(printf("Initializing b\n"), b)
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I successfully got around it by enclosing the comma operation by extra parentheses `a_((printf("Initializing a\n"), a)),` but I'm still a bit baffled what g++ was trying and failing to achieve in place of performing the comma operator as requested. Can someone explain?

Comment: *", no debugger readily available..."* You can use online debugger at : [onlinegdb](https://www.onlinegdb.com/)

Comment: @user12002570 For a short program, maybe. For a sizeable project that gets cross-compiled into an obscure architecture, not so much.

Comment: Yup, just mentioning an option. Better than having none.

Comment: You don't need all the extra stuff. You can reduce your program to just `int a{}; int b(printf("Initializing a\n"), a);`

Comment: In `a_(printf("Initializing a\n"), a)` you are in the meber initializer list.  That means `a(...)` is treated like you are "calling" a constrcutor (you can't actually call constructors).  That means its going to treat `printf("Initializing a\n")` and `a` as initializers for `a`.

Comment: Expressions like `a_(x, y)` are parsed as calling a constructor for `a_` with two parameters (in this context). Similarly, if `f` was a (possibly overloaded) function `f(x, y)` would try to pass two parameters `x` and `y` to the function and not `f(operator,(x,y))`.

Comment: Workaround: `a_(std::exchange(a, printf("Initializing a\n")))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ syntax for member initializer list includes a comma-separated list, for cases when the member needs several parameters to initialize:

```
struct small
{
    small(int x, int y, int z) {}
};

struct large
{
    small part1, part2;
    large(): part1(1, 2, 3), part2(22, 33, 44) {}
};
```

In your example, you have `int`, whose constructor has just one argument. But your code looks like it wants to invoke its constructor with 2 arguments. A separate interpretation of your code, the one you want, is invocation with a single argument which contains the comma-operator. If you want to choose it, you must use additional parentheses.

This is not an ambiguity in the grammar — a comma-separated list in that context means constructing with that number of arguments. But I guess the compiler is trying to be extra helpful, so it mentions this (illegal) interpretation of your code.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `a_(printf("Initializing a\n"), a)` is treated as a constructor call with two parameters which does not exist for `int`. When you put parentheses around, it is parsed as a single parameter. Thus you have a comma operator now inside.